# Prove $\frac{2\cos x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= \sec x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Prove that $\dfrac{2\cos x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= \sec x$.

So far I have:
$\dfrac{2\cos x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= \dfrac 1 {\cos x}$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: If you *really* have that then you've finished: $\;\sec x:=\frac1{\cos x}\;$

Comment: You should recall that $\cos(2x) = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichealHardy Or better : cos$2x=2cos^2x-1$

Comment: @N.S.JOHN : If you write \cos2x within MathJax, you'll see $\cos2x$, with proper spacing and matching fonts and font sizes, unlike cos$2x$.  And if you write "cos" with no backslash in MathJax, then you don't get proper spacing and you get italics that shouldn't be there. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a widespread practice for students to begin attempted proofs of trigonometric identities by writing things like this:
$$\frac{2\cos x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= \sec x$$
$$\frac{2\cos x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= \frac 1 {\cos x}$$

That's ok in scratchwork, but the finished proof should go like this:
$$
\sec x = \frac 1 {\cos x} = \cdots \cdots \cdots = \frac{2\cos x}{\cos2x + 1}
$$
or like this:
$$
\frac{2\cos x}{\cos2x + 1} = \cdots \cdots \cdots = \frac 1 {\cos x} = \sec x
$$
and of course to finish it you need to figure out what goes where all those dots are.

In other words, you put $\text{“}=\text{''}$ between things that you **already know** are equal.

Seeing $\cos(2x)$, you should recall the double-angle formula that says $\cos(2x) = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$.  Then you have
\begin{align}
\frac{2\cos x}{\cos(2x)+1} & = \frac{2\cos x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x + 1} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{2\cos x}{\cos^2 x + \cos^2 x} & & \text{since }-\sin^2x+1 = \cos^2 x \\[10pt]
& = \frac{2\cos x}{2\cos^2 x} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {\cos x} \\[10pt]
& = \sec x.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos (2x)}2
$$ and that
$$
\sec x=\frac1{\cos x}.
$$

Comment: I think its more direct to recall cos$2x=2cos^2x-1$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides with $\cos(x)$ and make use of the identity Olivier Oloa gave you and you are done.
$\dfrac{2\cos x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= \sec x  \to \dfrac{2\cos^2x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= 1 \to \dfrac{1+\cos 2x}{\cos 2x + 1 } = 1$

Well or just use the identity the other way around right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2\cos(x)}{1+\cos(2x)}=\sec(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\sec(x):=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$

---

$$\frac{2\cos(x)}{1+\cos(2x)}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2\cos^2(x)=1+\cos(2x)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$

---

$$2\cos^2(x)=1+2\cos^2(x)-1\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $1-1+2\cos^2(x)=0+2\cos^2(x)=2\cos^2(x)$

---

$$2\cos^2(x)=2\cos^2(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$$

When the above is plugged into the denominator, we have

$$\frac{2\cos x}{\cos 2x + 1 }= \frac {2\cos x}{2\cos^2x }=\frac1{\cos x} = \sec x$$